# Putting citation text on same slide with LaTeX Beamer

Tags: formatting, latex, beamer, citations

By default, using `\cite` in the Beamer class of LaTeX places the actual citation information at the end of the presentation on a separate slide containing the bibliography. How does one get the citation information, instead, on the same slide as the citation (the expected, courteous practice for most presentations)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package, you can insert a complete bibliographic entry with the `\fullcite` command.

Answer (score 9):

To have the citation at the bottom of the same slide, we can use `\footfullcite` instead of `\fullcite`.

Complete steps would be:

- Include  `\usepackage{biblatex}` and 
  `\bibliography{<your_bib_file>}` in your preamble.
- Use `\footfullcite{paper}` in your frame.

Comment: Instead of `\bibliography{biblio}` you should better use `\addbibressource{biblio.bib}` if you use the `biblatex` package

Comment: It is `\addbibresource{biblio.bib}` with a single s in resource.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the bibentry style for this (part of natbib), which just allows you to write `\bibentry{key}` which directly expands to the full bibliographic entry.

Answer (score 3):

So here is a minimal (but complete) working example: Assuming .bib file is named as biblio.bib:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text.\footnote{Some text in a footnote.} Some more text.\footcite{foo12}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\bibliography{biblio}` you should better use `\addbibressource{biblio.bib}` if you use the `biblatex` package